# Padding string with zeros in crystal report formula

Tags: string, sorting, crystal-reports, pad

I have some string whose max length cab be 4.
But the leading zeros are not present so I need to pad the same in string from left.
I am confused, as the string are like:

```
11A
12B
13
6
6A
```

Is there a way by which I can add leading zeros and then sort them, so that list can be like:

```
6
6A
11A
12B
13 and so on.
```

**Update:**
I had tried using padding zeros from right and specifying the length like:

```
Right("00" & TableField,3) as maximum can be three, but that is sorting as

6
13
6A
11A
12B
```

Comment: What kind of database do you use. Is your data always of the form NUMBER, NUMBER/LETTER or it can be something else, lets say NUMBER/LETTER/NUMBER.

Comment: It is the combination of sometimes number only, other time number+ alphabet as I have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an example for retrieving the sorted data with an SQL Query.

```
SELECT
    DATA
FROM 
    (
        SELECT '11A' AS DATA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '12B'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '13'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '6'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '6A'
    ) AS TestTable
ORDER BY
         LEN((
                CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(DATA) = 1
                    THEN LEFT(DATA + '0000', LEN(DATA) + 1)
                    ELSE DATA
                END
             )),
             (
                CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(DATA) = 1
                    THEN LEFT(DATA + '0000', LEN(DATA) + 1)
                    ELSE DATA
                END
             )
```

Comment: Have you tried the posted code as it is? Cause on SQL Server it gives the desired result.